# Game inventory system

Tags: python, beginner

I've been trying to figure out the best way to create a inventory system in Python. I like the way this one works but what I was wondering was if there was a better way to write it.

```
inv = ['Sword','Armor']
item_values = {'Sword':['Sword',5,1,15,2],
               'Armor':['Armor',0,10,25,5]}
print('Name\tAtk\tArm\tLb\tVal')
print(item_values[inv[0]][0],'\t',item_values[inv[0]][1],'\t',item_values[inv[0]][2],'\t',item_values[inv[0]][3],'\t',item_values[inv[0]][4])
print(item_values[inv[1]][0],'\t',item_values[inv[1]][1],'\t',item_values[inv[1]][2],'\t',item_values[inv[1]][3],'\t',item_values[inv[1]][4])
```

Comment: What exactly do you like about the way that one works?

Comment: Not directly related to the question, but tab formatting is generally a bad idea as there's no guarantee that the 'columns' will line up if certain values are longer than a 'column'. String formatting is the preferable way of formatting text. Some examples from the horse's mouth: https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples

Answer (score 8):

The items and the inventory can be modelled intuitively with classes:

- You can define an `Item` class that has attributes like `name`, `weight`, `attack`
- You can define an `Inventory` class that has a collection of items, and knows how to print them

Something like this:

```
class Item(object):
    def __init__(self, name, attack, armor, weight, price):
        self.name = name
        self.attack = attack
        self.armor = armor
        self.weight = weight
        self.price = price


class Inventory(object):    
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = {}

    def add_item(self, item):
        self.items[item.name] = item

    def print_items(self):
        print('\t'.join(['Name', 'Atk', 'Arm', 'Lb', 'Val']))
        for item in self.items.values():
            print('\t'.join([str(x) for x in [item.name, item.attack, item.armor, item.weight, item.price]]))


inventory = Inventory()
inventory.add_item(Item('Sword', 5, 1, 15, 2))
inventory.add_item(Item('Armor', 0, 10, 25, 5))
inventory.print_items()
```

**UPDATE**

Based on a suggestion by [@jonrsharpe](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/32391/jonrsharpe) you could move the printing logic from `print_items` to the `__str__` method:

```
def __str__(self):
    out = '\t'.join(['Name', 'Atk', 'Arm', 'Lb', 'Val'])
    for item in self.items.values():
        out += '\n' + '\t'.join([str(x) for x in [item.name, item.attack, item.armor, item.weight, item.price]])
    return out
```

This way, instead of `inventory.print_items()`, you can print the inventory more intuitively with `print(inventory)`.

Comment: Note that making `items` a class, rather than instance, attribute could cause problems later on (for example if the `Inventory` is also used for a shop or if a two-player mode is added); see [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1680528/3001761). You could also implement `__str__` and `__repr__` rather than providing an explicit printing method.

Comment: @jonrsharpe ouch, that was bad of me, thanks, fixed. I also considered using `__str__` and `__repr__`,  but a tricky thing with that is doing it in a way to keep the column ordering logic of the headers and the entries in one place, that's why I opted for an explicit printing method instead.

Comment: It still seems a bit awkward to define the method for displaying an `Item` in the `Inventory`, but I see what you mean - perhaps define a class attribute `Item.HEADERS`? Then `Inventory` can print the headers followed by `str(item)`.

Comment: Yeah I think it's awkward too. I think it's not a good idea after all. I don't think the `__str__` methods are for fine-tuning printing. I think the `__str__` method is good to write in a way that helps you in debugging. To pretty-print in some specific format, you should do it elsewhere.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want to go for a full class (which may be unnecessary if you won't have methods on your inventory or item instances), your other options include dictionaries:

```
inventory = {'Sword': {'attack': 5, 'defence': 1,
                       'weight': 15, 'price': 2},
             'Armor': {'attack': 0, 'defence': 10,
                       'weight': 25, 'price': 5}}

for name, item in inventory.items():
    print "{0}: {1[attack]} {1[defence]} {1[weight]} {1[price]}".format(name, item)
```

or a [`collections.namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#namedtuple-factory-function-for-tuples-with-named-fields):

```
from collections import namedtuple

Item = namedtuple('Item', ('attack', 'defence', 'weight', 'price'))
inventory = {'Sword': Item(5, 1, 15, 2),
             'Armor': Item(0, 10, 25, 5)}

for name, item in inventory.items():
    print "{0}: {1.attack} {1.defence} {1.weight} {1.price}".format(name, item)
```

Note the slightly different syntax for using these objects with `str.format` to create a more readable representation.

You can include the `'name'` in either of these structures, although at present it's duplicated information. It's also not clear why you have a separate list of the names; you can just iterate through the `inventory` keys.

Answer (score 1):

Combining ideas from the two earlier posts, you can use both a namedtuple and a custom `__str__` function that formats the string for each item:

```
from collections import namedtuple
Item = namedtuple('Item', ('name', 'attack', 'armor', 'weight', 'price'))

item_template = '{0.name:<10}' + ''.join('{{0.{field}:<5}}'.format(field=field) 
    for field in Item._fields[1:])
Item.__str__ = lambda item: item_template.format(item)
inventory_heading = Item('Name', 'Atk', 'Arm', 'Lb', 'Val')

inventory = [
    Item('sword', 5, 1, 15, 2),
    Item('armour', 0, 10, 25, 5)
]

for item in [inventory_heading] + inventory:
    print item
```

Going further, you could make inventory a class that inherits from list but which has its own `__str__` function too.

```
class Inventory(list):
    heading = Item('Name', 'Atk', 'Arm', 'Lb', 'Val')
    def __str__(self):
        return '\n'.join(map(str, [self.heading] + self))

inventory = Inventory([
    Item('sword', 5, 1, 15, 2),
    Item('armour', 0, 10, 25, 5)
])

print inventory
```

However, as you game gets more complicated you would probably want to move away from this type of approach to establish a division between what is displayed and the underlying game logic and data. This would tend to mean having a separate class or set of functions for managing the display output that are kept separate from your main game objects.